# Can't upgrade dotnet-sdk to 5.0.200

Tags: .net, macos, homebrew

While attempting to upgrade to latest dotnet-sdk on macOS I am getting the below error:

Error: dotnet-sdk: Failure while executing; `/usr/bin/sudo -E -- /bin/rmdir -- /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.406/Sdks/NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack/Desktop/tr` exited with 1. Here's the output:
sudo: 4294967295: invalid value
sudo: error initializing audit plugin sudoers_audit

Has anyone run into something similar?

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that the path(s) being referenced were empty and changing on every failed run. Thus after brute-forcing it 30-40 times, it finally upgraded.

`brew upgrade --greedy --force`